# configuring virtual host in xampp for magento installation

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp, virtualhost

I am very new to magento and php and i am trying to create a virtual host url for my magento site.

Currently the url is

```
http://localhost:8080/Magento/
```

And if i create any website i have to use url's such as below

```
http://localhost:8080/Magento/website1
http://localhost:8080/Magento/website2
...
```

After referring to several examples such as this http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/ i have managed to configure my files such as below

Step 1:
In the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` i have append the below mapping

```
127.0.0.1       clientA.local
```

Step 2:
And in the file  C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf i have append the below code

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
  <VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento"
    ServerName clientA.local
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After step 1 typing typing `clientA.local:8080/magento` opens localhost:8080/magento

But step 2 doesn't change anything.

I want to do something as below

```
clientA.local should open http://localhost:8080/Magento/website1
clientB.local should open http://localhost:8080/Magento/website2
...
```

I have tried changing the Document root , directory in several ways nothing helped.

If any one has any idea on this senario please contribute here.

thanx

Comment: You can make directory like this :: http://localhost:8080/Magento/
http://localhost:8080/Magento1/

Comment: @Ankit no that would be different installations of magento.. i need to have multiple sites under the same magento installation